# ASP.NET WebForms project sub-domains routing?

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have ASP.NET project(WebForms not MVC) to manage companies Project,Logs,ToDos, etc......

I want to allow user to access the site with url start with their company name. for example:

my site is `www.mysite.com`

i want to allow users to access my site like this

`www.company1.mysite.com` or `www.company2.mysite.com` or `www.companyX.mysite.com`

and then inside my code i could get the `comanyX` part.

can you give me any clues how to do this pragmatically or what steps i should do on my server or inside my code

not i'm using ASP.NET WebForms not MVC.

Comment: What you want to achieve is called multi-tenancy. These might give intersting clues : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9566970/1236044 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9047639/1236044

Comment: @jbl can you give me clear steps of what i should do? and is there any changes i should make on the server or the DNS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you have to do is set up a wildcard DNS entry `*.mysite.com` see ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record ) so that any url ending with .mysite.com end up on your server.

Then, you have several options, two of these are :

- in your pages, recover the host name through parsing of  `Request.Url.Host`, as shown in ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/9566970/1236044 )
- set up a domain routing logic, as in http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/aspnet-mvc-domain-routing.aspx